# PHP Loop to get already selected <select> element values

Tags: php, loops, if-statement, for-loop, while-loop

My loop below finds the first instance of "selected" and then no more.  The output should say "selected" for FARM and COUNTRY but only farm comes back.  Sample output is below.  I know it's just the order I have the WHILE, FOR and IF statements but I can't figure it out.

Partial sample output:

category NOT selected "SKY"
category selected "FARM"
category NOT selected "CITY"
category NOT selected "TOWN"
category NOT selected "COUNTRY"

The value of $row is 100 and $wordChunks is 2.

```
$wordChunks = explode(" | ", $categoryquery1['companycategory']);
$sql = "SELECT category_name FROM company_categories " . " ORDER BY category_name";
$rs = mysql_query($sql);for($i = 0; $i < count($wordChunks); $i++)
{

while($row = mysql_data_seek($rs, 0)
{ 

if ($wordChunks[$i] == $row['category_name'])
{
  echo "category selected \"".$row['category_name']."\"<br />"; 
}
else {
    echo "category NOT selected \"".$row['category_name']."\"<br />";
}   
}
}
```

Comment: there is one missing `else`: `if (...) { echo ... } else { echo ... }`

Comment: try `else{` after the 8th line

Comment: OK we're getting closer.  Now it doesn't print 3 times for the selected elements.  Now it prints everything twice.  It will print the "selected line" and then a "not selected" line for the "selected" elements.

Comment: post your updated code and results

Comment: Updated code and output.

Comment: value is 2.  It is basically the amount of items that are "selected".

Comment: how do you say value of `$row` is 100 ?? Its an array actually..

Comment: There is 100 items in the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out,

```
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs))
    {
        if (in_array($row['category_name'], $wordChunks))
        {
            echo "category selected \"" . $row['category_name'] . "\"<br />";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "category NOT selected \"" . $row['category_name'] . "\"<br />";
        }
    }
```

Please dont use `mysql_*` extensions, use `mysqli_*` instead.

Comment: Sorry that didn't even show the page for me.  I did update my code and output above. It now finds the "first" selected element but then doesnt find any others.  And it only prints everything once now so we are getting closer!